# How to have mocha show entire object in diff on assertion error?

Tags: javascript, typescript, mocha.js, diff, chai

I have a unit test test case created with mocha and chai's expect where I deeply compare an array of value objects to the parsed content of a JSON file.

My record object has about 20 properties, and currently only the price can cause a mismatch. On a diff, I only see five of them.

```
 expect(records).to.deep.equal(expected);

       "data": {
  -      "price": 3578
  +      "price": 3438
         "not_important": "foo"
         "also_not_important": "bar"
       }
       "data": {
  -      "price": 1828
  +      "price": 1698
         "not_important": "foo"
         "also_not_important": "bar"
       }
```

This is useful default in most cases, yet in this one it obfuscates which specific data object is breaking the assertions, as I only see redundant data here.

Assume there is a `important` property in the data object that would make it quite clear what expectation is breaking the test. Therefore, I would like to be able to either configure what properties are shown or to display the entire object in the diff.

How can I configure mocha's diff display?

---

Here is a contrived meta-syntactic example showcasing the problem:

```
import {expect} from "chai";

describe(("diff problem"), () => {
    it("should show case that the diff is not shown properly", () => {
        const actual = {
            a: 1,
            troiz: 0,
            bar: 0,
            baz: 2,
            poit: 3,
            narf: 4,
            fizzbuzz: 117,
            fizz: 5,
            buzz: 4,
            waldo: 115,
            mos: 85465,
            important: "THIS IS IMPORTANT",
        };

        const expected = {
            ...actual,
            a: 0,
        };

        return expect(actual).to.deep.equal(expected);
    });
});
```

The output of that testcase will be:

2) SourceParser diff problem should show entire diff on error of one property:

```
  AssertionError: expected { Object (a, troiz, ...) } to deeply equal { Object (a, troiz, ...) }
  + expected - actual

   {
  -  "a": 1
  +  "a": 0
     "bar": 0
     "baz": 2
     "buzz": 4
     "fizz": 5
```

Yet it would be helpful to see: `important: "THIS IS IMPORTANT"` as well.

---

Here is the modified example for the array case:

```
describe(("diff problem with an array"), () => {
    it("should show case that the diff is not shown properly for deep equal of arrays", () => {
        const anEntity = {
            a: 1,
            troiz: 0,
            bar: 0,
            baz: 2,
            poit: 3,
            narf: 4,
            fizzbuzz: 117,
            fizz: 5,
            buzz: 4,
            waldo: 115,
            mos: 85465,
            important: "IMPORTANT", // assume that each item has a unique important property, which is why it's helpful for it to be shown
        };

        const offendingItem = {
            ...anEntity,
            a: 0,
        };

        const actual = [
            anEntity,
            offendingItem,
            anEntity,
        ];

        const expected = [
            anEntity,
            anEntity,
            anEntity,
        ];

        return expect(actual).to.deep.equal(expected);
    });
```

The output will be:

```
  AssertionError: expected [ Array(3) ] to deeply equal [ Array(3) ]
  + expected - actual

       "troiz": 0
       "waldo": 115
     }
     {
  -    "a": 0
  +    "a": 1
       "bar": 0
       "baz": 2
       "buzz": 4
       "fizz": 5
```

and it won't get better with Louis' answer modifying chai as it only dumps the entire actual array first and then shows the non-helpful diff:

```
AssertionError: expected [ { a: 1,
    troiz: 0,
    bar: 0,
    baz: 2,
    poit: 3,
    narf: 4,
    fizzbuzz: 117,
    fizz: 5,
    buzz: 4,
    waldo: 115,
    mos: 85465,
    important: 'IMPORTANT' },
  { a: 0,
    troiz: 0,
    bar: 0,
    baz: 2,
    poit: 3,
    narf: 4,
    fizzbuzz: 117,
    fizz: 5,
    buzz: 4,
    waldo: 115,
    mos: 85465,
    important: 'IMPORTANT' },
  { a: 1,
    troiz: 0,
    bar: 0,
    baz: 2,
    poit: 3,
    narf: 4,
    fizzbuzz: 117,
    fizz: 5,
    buzz: 4,
    waldo: 115,
    mos: 85465,
    important: 'IMPORTANT' } ] to deeply equal [ { a: 1,
    troiz: 0,
    bar: 0,
    baz: 2,
    poit: 3,
    narf: 4,
    fizzbuzz: 117,
    fizz: 5,
    buzz: 4,
    waldo: 115,
    mos: 85465,
    important: 'IMPORTANT' },
  { a: 1,
    troiz: 0,
    bar: 0,
    baz: 2,
    poit: 3,
    narf: 4,
    fizzbuzz: 117,
    fizz: 5,
    buzz: 4,
    waldo: 115,
    mos: 85465,
    important: 'IMPORTANT' },
  { a: 1,
    troiz: 0,
    bar: 0,
    baz: 2,
    poit: 3,
    narf: 4,
    fizzbuzz: 117,
    fizz: 5,
    buzz: 4,
    waldo: 115,
    mos: 85465,
    important: 'IMPORTANT' } ]
      + expected - actual

           "troiz": 0
           "waldo": 115
         }
         {
      -    "a": 0
      +    "a": 1
           "bar": 0
           "baz": 2
           "buzz": 4
           "fizz": 5
```

Comment: @Louis It shouldn't matter though as [chai is appearantly not taking care of the diff](https://github.com/chaijs/chai/issues/469#issuecomment-153759558)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add `--inline-diffs` to the mocha command, which will show the entire object with line numbers and inline diffs:

```
mocha --inline-diffs YourSpec.js
```

The documentation is a bit misleading: https://mochajs.org/#diffs

[image: The mocha result]

Comment: When running mocha as library (like in Postman tests) - is it still possible?

Answer (score 13):

As far as I know, there's no built-in way to get Chai or Mocha to produce diffs that would add to the context provided by the diff some fields that are not *responsible* for the test failure. And I'm not aware of any extension that would exactly what you are looking for. So I only know of workarounds.

---

If you set `truncateThreshold` configuration setting to a larger value, or to `0` if you don't want any truncation, the failure message that appears before the diff will show whole objects. So if I add this to your code:

```
chai.config.truncateThreshold = 0; // 0 means "don't truncate, ever".
```

(The configuration options are covered on this [documentation page](http://chaijs.com/guide/styles/).)

Then the error I get is:

```
      AssertionError: expected { a: 1,
  troiz: 0,
  bar: 0,
  baz: 2,
  poit: 3,
  narf: 4,
  fizzbuzz: 117,
  fizz: 5,
  buzz: 4,
  waldo: 115,
  mos: 85465,
  important: 'THIS IS IMPORTANT' } to deeply equal { a: 0,
  troiz: 0,
  bar: 0,
  baz: 2,
  poit: 3,
  narf: 4,
  fizzbuzz: 117,
  fizz: 5,
  buzz: 4,
  waldo: 115,
  mos: 85465,
  important: 'THIS IS IMPORTANT' }
      + expected - actual

       {
      -  "a": 1
      +  "a": 0
         "bar": 0
         "baz": 2
         "buzz": 4
         "fizz": 5
```

Moreover, a way to get custom information in the error message is to set a custom message with the assertion, for instance:

```
expect(actual).to.deep.equal(
            expected,
            `failed equality test on object with important field set to: ${actual.important}`)
```

The custom message can be as verbose or terse as you need it to be.

If there is only one field that matters to you for differentiating objects, a custom message may be sufficient to get the information you need to track the problem.

---

For arrays of objects, you could perform a comparison by iterating through the `actual` and `expected` arrays and comparing each member. It would then essentially work like described above. For sure, this has disadvantages: if items 1 and 10 are different, for instance, you'll get a report only for item 1 because the test will end with that comparison failure. When you fix this problem and run the test again, you'll get a report for item 10. Whether or not in practice this is a major problem depends the kind of data you are testing.

---

One thing I've done in cases where the default diff algorithm was not doing what I wanted was to import a diffing library that I configured to my liking, and then use the library to perform diffs between objects that I cared about and combine the results into a final report that is then checked with an assertion.

Again, I'm not aware of a library that would do *specifically* what you are looking for. However, I could imagine iterating through the `actual` and `expected` arrays to produce one diff report per pair and then combining them into a larger report that contains identifying information.

Comment: Thank you very much, after looking the documentation: https://www.chaijs.com/guide/styles/#configuration I solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone struggling with the issue when running mocha tests in a browser (regular or headless). A simple fix could get the needed diffs explicitly printed next to the error while focussing on actual differences. This saves time for debugging the errors:

```js
import chai from 'chai'

function chaiExtensions(chai, {flag}) {
  const {assert} = chai.Assertion.prototype

  chai.Assertion.prototype.assert = function (...args) {
    try {
      assert.apply(this, args)
    } catch (e) {
      if (e.operator === 'deepStrictEqual' && e.showDiff) {
        e.message = `\n${prettyjson.render(
          deepDiff(e.actual, e.expected)
        )}\n\n${e.message}`
      }
      throw e
    }
  }
}

chai.use(specHelper.chaiExtensions)
```

Where diff resolver func and  pretty print could be done of your choice. In my case:

`deepDiff`: https://gist.github.com/Yimiprod/7ee176597fef230d1451?permalink_comment_id=4757803#gistcomment-4757803

`prettyjson`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/prettyjson

Answer (score -6):

Note due to all the downvotes: I am the OP. My intended solution is not addressing the actual issue of my architecture decision. Having a solution that compares huge objects is a code smell. I have refactored my code base so that I am not in need of this attempted solution anymore.

---

You are trying to solve the wrong problem. Your intended solutions is only a workaround.

Your actual problem is to rely on on deep comparing a huge array of huge objects to begin with.

You should refactor your codebase to allow price calculation through a price calculation service. Unit testing that service is straightforward with simple asserts.